# what is the maximum no of store statement possible in pig script?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

Till now I have used only two store statement in a pig script.Is there any restriction of using multiple store statement in a single script of PIG?

```
 A = load 'page_views'; 
store A into 'tmp1' using PigStorage();
 B = load 'tmp1' using PigStorage();
 C = filter B by $0 is not null; 
store C into 'tmp2';
....
....
store D into 'tmp3';
```

Comment: Please consider providing more information on your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts with multiple store commands *can* result in a lot of duplicated work, but this very much depends on how you use PIG. Technically speaking, there is no maximum number of store statements within a single script. However, you may experience some performance issues, if you *are doing it wrong*. There is a quite neat write-up about performance in the [Apache PIG Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigMultiQueryPerformanceSpecification), you might find useful reading. In terms of multi-query optimization, there is also [an issue filed in Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-627).

Comment: thank you for your quick response. What kind of duplicate happen?and how it will hamper performance. Consider above scenario

Comment: The duplication is mostly about processing separate parts of the same data stream with different processes. Storing intermediate results prevents you from doing the same thing twice, for example. But as I said before, this varies from use case to use case very much. Read up on the references I provided.